# Passing Parameters from Visualforce Email Template to Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to pass some parameters from my Visualforce Template to a Lightning Component.

My code is

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Welcome to {!$Label.Community_Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Network">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Hi {!Recipient.FirstName},

Welcome to {!$Label.Community_Name}! To get started, go to {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}

Username: {!Recipient.Username}

Thanks,
{!$Organization.Name}

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I have to pass `{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}` and `{!Recipient.Username}` as parameters to Lightning Component.

Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your question does not make a lot of sense as written.

Comment: I want to pass 2 parameters from VF Email Template to a Lightning Component.

i.e. {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} and {!Recipient.Username}

How can i pass these 2 parameters from my Visualforc template to a Lightning Component?

Is it possible? 
Please help.